Understanding Docker/ETL/Pentaho
I'm having problems undestending this:
http://kettletdf:8000/etl/v1/eph/enriched/listar
I know that kettletdf is the container's name.
I don't know fron where is getting this?
./etl/v1/eph/enriched/listar isn't a folder
I got the query from this :
    response = requests.get(etl_baseurl + etl_version + etl_fuente + folder + "/listar", timeout=settings.REQUEST_EPH_TIMEOUT)
    data = response.json()

yml:
services:
  kettletdf:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: etl/kettle/Dockerfile
      args:
        GIT_BRANCH: ${GIT_BRANCH}
        GIT_USER: ${GIT_USER}
        GIT_PASS: ${GIT_PASS}
        GIT_REPO: ${GIT_REPO}

    env_file:
      - .env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    container_name: kettletdf
    #ports:
      #- "${KETTLE_PORT}:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_NAME=${POSTGRES_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - CSV_VOLUME_FULLPATH=${CSV_VOLUME_FULLPATH}
    volumes:
      #AGREGAR RUTAS DE ARCHVISPOS FAÑLTANTES (ETC/SALUD/ORIGINFILES ... COMERCIO ,....ETC)
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ../eph/eph_csv_origin_file:/opt/tdf/volumes/eph_csv_origin_file/
      - ../eph/eph_csv_master_file:/opt/tdf/volumes/eph_csv_master_file/
      - ../eph/eph_csv_enriched_file:/opt/tdf/volumes/eph_csv_enriched_file/
      - ../eph/eph_csv_cuadros_resultado:/opt/tdf/volumes/eph_csv_cuadros_resultado/
      - ../eph/sintaxis_r_resultado:/opt/tdf/volumes/sintaxis_r_resultado/
      - ../eph/sintaxis_r_resultado:/opt/tdf/datalaketdf/etl/eph/sintaxis_r_resultado/
      # Queda comentado para que no pise los scripts dentro de eph
        #- ../eph/:/opt/tdf/datalaketdf/etl/eph/
      - ../eph/bdd/scripts/:/opt/tdf/volumes/scripts/
      - ../salud/:/opt/tdf/datalaketdf/etl/salud/
      - ../salud/bdd/scripts/:/opt/tdf/volumes/salud_scripts/
      # Actualizar cada vez que se quiera agregar / quitar una carpta dentro de KETTER
      - /opt/tdf/volumes/salud_archivos/xls_origin_file
      - /opt/tdf/volumes/comercio_exterior/origen
      - /opt/tdf/volumes/comercio_exterior/nomencladores
      # Actualizar cada vez que se quiera agregar / quitar una carpta dentro de KETTER

      # Queda comentado por que saca el codigo del repo en git
      #- ../api:/opt/tdf/datalaketdf/etl/api
    networks:
      - datalaketdf
networks:
   datalaketdf:
     external: true


If this is being run via Docker, then it could be that the container expects a volume mapping; what syntax is being used to launch this?

@mikequentel I don't know if the yml help?

try logging into the running container (docker exec -it kettletdf sh) and search for listar; I suspect this is either a problem with the volume mapping, or maybe the .env file). When an expected file is missing from a referenced mapping, Docker might create it as a "phantom" directory.
